# Postgres: return true/false if matches found from inner join?

Tags: postgresql

I have implemented a tagging system in my application, using Postgres 9.6. There are three tables.

Projects

```
                                         Table "public.project"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |             Default             
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------
 id          | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('tag_id_seq'::regclass)
 name         | character varying(255)      |           | not null | 
 user_id     | integer                     |           |          |
```

Tags

```
                                         Table "public.tag"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |             Default             
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------
 id          | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('tag_id_seq'::regclass)
 tag         | character varying(255)      |           | not null | 
 user_id     | integer                     |           |          | 
 is_internal | boolean                     |           | not null | false
```

Project tags

```
      Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default                 
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 id               | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('project_tag_id_seq'::regclass)
 tag_id           | integer                     |           | not null | 
 project_id | integer                     |           |          |        | 
 user_id          | integer                     |           | not null |
```

Now I want to get a list of all the projects, annotated with a column that indicates (for a particular tag) whether it has that tag.

So I'd like the results to look like this:

```
id          name          has_favorite_tag
1           foo           true
2           bar           false
3           baz           false
```

This is my query so far:

```
select project.*, CASE(XXXX) as has_project_tag
from project p
join (select * from project_tag where tag_id=1) pt on p.id=pt.project_id
```

I know that I want to use CASE to be true when the length of `project_tag` matches is greater than 0 - but how do I do this?

(In reality the project table has many more fields, of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility (unfiltered for tag_id; add to inner select if necessary):

```
select project.*, exists(select * from project_tag where id=project.id) as has_project_tag from project;
```